# Android - How to alert user, if wants his entered data to be saved, on back key?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-lifecycle

In user enter data, UI/UX screen there are 'Save', 'Cancel' buttons. If user enters some data, BUT taps Back key, I need to display (AlertDialog) whether he wants to save the data or not.  How can be done ?

I think this should be done on something like: @override onDestroy() ? but unable to (kind of) hold/pause onDestroy() and display the AlertDialog !

This would be something similar to what 'Microsoft Word' does, but in Android.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(needsSave){
            .
            .
            .
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method specifically for this purpose, it's called when the user presses the back button on their device.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
   ..call the dialog builder here..
}
```

you can use super.onBackPressed() method when the user presses
either the positive or negative buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Fragment you can Pass Listener and then you can listen whenever user presses back button you will be notified.

create interface.

```
interface IOnBackPressed {
    fun onBackPressed(): Boolean
}
```

in your Activity.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
     override fun onBackPressed() {
        val fragment =
            this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_container)
        (fragment as? IOnBackPressed)?.onBackPressed()?.not()?.let {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

}
```

in your Fragment.

```
class YourFragmentName : Fragment(), IOnBackPressed {

    override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
            //Create Your Dialog.
           //Dialog.Positive.clicked return true
          //Dialog.Negate.clicked return false
    }
}
```